# Symmetric group with elements of prime order

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If $S_n$ is the symmetric group on $n$ letters and $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers, I know the smallest $n$ such that $S_n$ has an element of prime $p$ is $p$. What about an element of $p^2$? $pq$?

Comment: Do you know how to characterize the order of a permutation in terms of its decomposition in disjoint cycles ?

Comment: To complete @CaptainLama comment, the order of a permutation is the lowest common multiple of the size of its cycles (see *https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutation_order* for more definitions and examples). Hence if you want that the order of your permutation is a multiple of $p$ you need a cycle of size a multiple of $p$, and in the same fashion you'll  need a cycle of size (a multiple of) $p$ and another of size  (a multiple of) $q$ *or* a cycle of size (a multiple of) $pq$ to get a permutation of order (a multiple of) $pq$.